# Wordpress theme made with Angular2+ is not displaying

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, angular

I got interested in using wordpress with angular, so I used google, and came on a tutorial that shows how to create a WP theme with Angular.

[tutorial](http://doppiaeast.com/article/angular-2-wordpress-theme-setup/)

I created a basic Angular app using `ng new`, I ran `ng serve` and opened up it in localhost. Works fine, basic Angular app etc. Great. So I followed a tutorial and created inside root index.php, functions.php and style.css.

After that, in the CLI I ran *ng build* and got a dist folder, and then I archived dist folder, index.php, functions.php and style.css in a zip file. Installed WP on Azure, and added a theme. Instalation of the theme went like usuall, no problems, but the page is not displayed. There is no angular logo like when it comes with a newly created project.

A link of the site.

[site](http://wpang.azurewebsites.net/)

I have no idea why the theme is not being displayed. Can anyone guide me how to fix this?

Comment: have you checked `error_logs` ?

Comment: In the console, I get 8 404's.. No idea how

Comment: have you tested your project on local server ?

Comment: @3gth I have tested only Angular app and runs no problem. All I did was follow the tutorial and upload theme to Azure. Now I have no idea why it wont run

Comment: you can see in the comments section of the mentioned tutorial how one user fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!
Build Angular app with this.

```
ng build --prod --deploy-url="/wp-content/themes/theme-name/dist/"
```